# Insertion mode mapping to save file in insertion mode

Tags: vim, vi

I'm new to vim script. What I want to achieve is to enable saving a file with `<C-S>` when in Insertion mode. So I added this line to my vimrc file to map the keys together:

```
inoremap <C-S> <C-O>:w<CR>
```

The problem is that it doesn't do anything when trying it, even though it is listed in the insertion mode key maps.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you running vim inside a terminal emulator? What happens when you press `<C-V><C-S>` in insert mode?

Comment: @melpomene, I'm running vim in a bash terminal. When pressing the given command, it appends a '^' character at the position of my cursor.

Comment: Your terminal is eating the Ctrl-S key, then. Vim never sees it.

Comment: http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/mapping-ctrls-does-not-work

Comment: For the explanation of `inoremap <C-S> <C-O>:w<CR>`, see https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/22489/